# Select no. of people based on values in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows :-

**Table 1**

```
Id_1    Name            Country     status1     flag
===================================================
1     Person AB          IN          1           0
2     Person BC          US          1           0 
3     Person CD          UK          1           0
4     Person DE          IN          1           0
```

**Table 2**

```
Id_2     Role            Gender     status2     flag
===================================================
1        rol1             Female     1           0
2        rol2             Male       1           0 
3        rol3             Male       1           0
4        rol4             Female     1           0
```

**I want to count the number of *Females* living in *IN* and status1 = 1**

I have this MySQL Statement :-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) into TotalFemales FROM Table1 tb1 JOIN Table2 tb2 
on tb1.Id_1=tb2.Id_2
WHERE tb1.flag=false and tb1.Country='IN' and tb1.status1=1 a tb2.Gender='Female';
```

But, I am getting 0 everytime.

Comment: tb2.Country='IN' ?? tb1.country surely and JOIN Table 2  is incorrect there should be no space between table and 2

Comment: @P.Salmon I rectified my typos

Comment: Tb1.flag=0 instead of false

Comment: Here is a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6GxvcnJTD1PstnnpqZ8aKD/1). It seems to work (barring a few typos). Maybe your issue comes from the fact you `SELECT ... INTO` a variable, which "eats" the result?

Answer (score 0):

Use `flag = 0` (instead of `false`), and it seems that you have a typo in your `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
into TotalFemales 
FROM Table1 tb1 
JOIN Table2 tb2 
    on tb1.Id_1=tb2.Id_2
WHERE tb1.flag=0 
    and tb1.Country='IN' 
    and tb1.status1=1 
    and tb2.Gender='Female';

SELECT * FROM TotalFemales;
```