# Select only a number of rows from a pandas Dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, where-clause, rows

I'm want to sample n rows from each different value in column named **club**

[image]

```
columns = ['long_name','age','dob','height_cm','weight_kg','club']
teams = ['Real Madrid','FC Barcelona','Chelsea','CA Osasuna','Paris Saint-Germain','FC Bayern München','Atlético Madrid','Manchester City','Liverpool','Hull City']
playersDataDB = playersData.loc[playersData['club'].isin(teams)][columns]
playersDataDB.head()
```

In the code above i have selected my desired colums based on them belonging to the teams selected.

The output from this code is a 299 rows × 6 columns Dataframe meaning that i'm sampling all the player from the team but i want to get just 16 of them from each club.

Comment: Please add some sample input and expected output.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Also have you tried `playersData.loc[playersData['club'].isin(teams), columns]`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal i've updated my question. What i want is to get 16 rows from each category in this case from the column 'club'

Comment: @aarribas12 your original question was already answered by someone. Now you're asking for something else. Please ask a new question instead of changing the original one.

Comment: Also, when you ask the new question, please provide the data so that the solution can be tested. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66817651/1271772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your dataframe looks like but you could groupby teams and then use head(16) to get only the first 16 of them.

```
df.groupby('club').head(16)
```

Comment: Dataframe is indexed by a footballer ID so this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` like this:

```
playersDataDB = playersData[playersData['club'].isin(teams)]
playersDataDB.head()
```